# How do I fix my logo from overlapping my menu?

Tags: css

My logo is overlapping my menu bar I just went to space it from overlapping

I tried changing the code but I'm a novelist so I really don't know what works I know about HTML but it's not the same.

`.navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.nav { right: 10px; }`

Whenever I change the code it messes up the font size and it still over lamps

Here is the website:http://143wear.com

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: I have checked the issue was with the bootstap grid issue in the header.

Comment: .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.nav { right: 10px; }

Comment: So how would I fix the issue?

Comment: You can rig a quick fix by editing the style of the menu list, but that won't work across all devices. Do you have separate styling for mobile vs. desktop? This stops it from overlapping on desktop: `<ul id="primary-menu" class="nav navbar-nav megamenu" style="position: relative; left: 15em !important;">`

Comment: Yep one is for mobile and the other one for desktop that is correct. Thank you for your help

Comment: If editing the stylesheet: 
`ul#primary-menu {
position: relative; left: 15em !important;
}`

Comment: You can just change HTML. For `header-logo col-md-3 col-lg-2` to change class for header-right, too `header-right col-md-2`

Comment: http://prntscr.com/o2qe5o

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
}

.header-logo {
    width: auto;
}

.header-right {
    width: auto;
}

.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Would be a working solution (might need some improvements for responsibility)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using WordPress, through Admin dashboard you can set the `max-width: 146px;` to Logo,
Else you can use the following code into CSS,

By using this code there will be least chances for responsiveness issues,
In case you need bigger logo, you have to customize the code.

```
.site-header .logo img {
    max-width: 146px;
}
```

Comment: I put in the code you gave me when the pixels are smaller it works but when I get to the 300 threshold it still overlaps. Thank you for your help